# ide sublime2 how to find method definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext

I'm using **Sublime 2** for Ruby On Rails programming.
I need a ability to click a method name and jump to class where the method is defined. There are many IDE with similar capability...

Comment: As a textmate switcher I've been missing this.

Comment: But currently there is no such option. Am I right?

Comment: Sublime text 3 now has this feature (http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-beta), though I don't know if upgrading to ST3 works for you.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I already know about it.

Comment: Compared some plugins for ST here. Although I'm using Python, most of these plugins aren't python specific http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914386/sublime-text-2-3-setup-for-python-django-with-code-completion

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Goto symbol` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (linux), this gives a pop-up-list of all symbol and class definitions in the file, in definition order, and you can jump to what you're after. You could do the same thing with `Goto Anything`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and then typing <kbd>@</kbd> and the method name.

Also, there is a [Goto Symbol](https://github.com/gooli/Goto-Symbol) plugin, which lets you jump straight to the definition of the method name your cursor is at, with a key binding or click.

However, both those methods are limited to the current file. If you need to jump to definitions in other files, probably the best solution is the [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin. It seems to be working pretty well and just by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f3</kbd> (linux) will open up the file at the definition you want.

Comment: superb advie thanks re sublimecodeintel - the lack of a find-in-project command is a remarkable omission from Sublime I was about to ditch it and go back to BBedit until I found your post

Comment: this is a good answer but unfortunately SublimeCodeIntel seems quite buggy, so my advice is to not waste time with it and try CTags instead as suggested by @alienhard

Answer (score 27):

Another solution is **CTags**.

SublimeCodeIntel seems to be pretty buggy judging from [unresolved issues](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel/issues) on the Github tracker. Also it crashes for me, probably because the code base I'm working on is too big...

What I'm using now is the [CTags package](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags). There's no "intelligence" but it allows you to jump to definitions and back very easily and it is super fast.

Comment: How to do this process.I tried ctrl+click in the function call.but it is not jumping to function definition

Comment: I'm using these custom mappings:

{
    "command": "navigate_to_definition",
    "keys": ["ctrl+option+]"]
  },
  {
    "command": "jump_back",
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+["]
  },

but obviously you can define your own.

Comment: The problem is that it can only go to function definitions, but can't find variable definitions.

Comment: For spanish layout: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+x"], "command": "navigate_to_definition"},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+z"], "command": "jump_back"}`

Comment: been 3 years, I wonder if they have any new package available to solve the issue of finding variable definitions

Answer (score 5):

upgrade to sublime text 3 and then put cursor on function name and click F12
to go back ALT+-
or from the menu click on Goto