# Sublime text quick search plugin

Tags: eclipse, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In eclipse I can do Ctrl + Shift + M to search for a method that exists in ANY file in the project, however this feature seems to be missing from sublime text ... is there any sort of Sublime text plugin that replicates this functionality?

I know that there's Ctrl+P etc, however that only searches for functions in the currently opened file and not from the entire project.

Comment: In ST2, SublimeCodeIntel may be the best way to go about it (I haven't used it much). But I wanted to say this functionality is built into ST3 if you own a license/decide purchase one and upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276340/ide-sublime2-how-to-find-method-definition) also gives a better answer. But in essence, get sublime code intel from packages, and then when you press `CTRL` + `R`, you can just jump to any method of your choice.