# How to make Sublime Text3 display all methods just with a dot

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I'm new to python and trying to find out a way to display all the methods associated with any of the external modules i might use like pyodbc.
How to edit my user settings to display the methods just with

```
<Object>.
```

Tried with Anaconda as suggested, but it was just able to work for string and may be other types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 & 3 setup for python / django with code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914386/sublime-text-2-3-setup-for-python-django-with-code-completion)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for a string when i added anaconda. But will edit my question